# Ask for a html var and pass to JS

Tags: javascript, html, var

I have created a working Binary to Decimal Calculator but would like a `HTML input`.

```
<html>
<input placeholder="00000000" name="htmlinput"></input>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Go" onclick="runbintodec();"></input>
</html>


<script>
function runbintodec()
{
    var bin = document.getElementByName('htmlinput').value;
    ...(Bin to Dec Calc code)
}
</script>
```

I need some way to take an input from a `html input form` and send it to the script when i click the button 'go'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,  `input` is a non-closing tag. Secondly, there's nothing like `document.getElementByName`, use `document.getElementsByName` instead or even better - assign an unique `id` identifier to your `input` and then catch it by `document.getElementById`.

```js
function runbintodec() {
  var bin = document.getElementsByName('htmlinput')[0].value;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="00000000" name="htmlinput">
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Go" onclick="runbintodec();">
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I cannot accept your answer for another 8 minutes.